# Determinator of matrix operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

find the determinant of the operator $K[x]_{\leq n} \to K[x]_{\leq n}$ specified by the formula:
$f(x) \rightarrow f(x) + x \cdot f'(x+1)$

I've tried to solve it, but the binomial coefficients came out and it made me scared.

Comment: Maybe "determinant" ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the map on the canonical basis $\;\{1,x,...,x^n\}\;$ of $\;K_n[x]\;$ to find out a nice matrix representation of the linear map $\;Tp(x):=p(x)+xp'(x+1)\;$:

$$\begin{cases}T1=1+x\cdot0=1=&1\cdot1+&0\cdot x+\ldots+\ldots+0\cdot x^n\\{}\\
Tx=x+x\cdot1=2x=&0\cdot1+&2x+\ldots+\ldots+0\cdot x^n\\{}\\
Tx^2=x^2+2x(x+1)=&0\cdot1+&2\cdot x+3\cdot x^2+\ldots+0\cdot x^n\\{}\\
..................................\\{}\\
Tx^n=x^n+nx(x+1)^{n-1}=&0\cdot1+&nx+n(n-1)x^2+\ldots+(1+n)x^n\end{cases}$$

The above is a lower triangular matrix $\;(n+1)\times(n+1)\;$ , so its determinant is easy to evaluate...(though the actual matrix is the transpose of the above, but since $\;\det A=\det(A^t)\;$ for any square matrix $\;A\;$ , we've no problem).

Of course, this is in case you meant "Determinant" ...